# Server stopped but port 3000 still being used and localhost accessible

Tags: networking, terminal, webserver, ruby-on-rails, rails

So I have a rails server running on port 3000. I shutdown my rails server, but it still shows up on my processes like this:

> ```
> ps -ef | grep rails
>   501 49901 34171   0  1:36PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn rails
> ```

Everytime I run ps -ef, the pid is different, meaning its changing all the time and I assume it is because of that that I can't kill this process through its pid.

I also use redis and sidekiq, and they also show up in

> ps -ef

in a similar manner.

My questions are:

1. Why is the pid changing all the time?
2. What exactly are all those '--exclude-dir' for?
3. Why is it showing in the ps at all?
4. Is it a cached version of the website? If so, how do I clear that, and is it because of any of the services I use?
5. How do I kill this process?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you notice what command is showing up in the line returned by "ps -ef | grep XXX" ? What happens if you try, for example, "ps -ef | grep thisisatest" (or any other non-existent process name) and see if you understand what is happening. Hint: there is no process running with that name but the ps | grep still returns a line.

Comment: @StarCat Thanks for the tips. So the process is actually the grep command running! Interesting. So now I assume it is in fact a cached version of the website. Not all pages work. I think it's supposed to be this way. I wonder if it is a programmed behaviour or default by the browser or something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is due to caching. Service Worker was caching home page.